# Running composer-playground in docker container doesn't connect to fabric network

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have setup a fabric network with 2 peers with couch db, 1 orderer, 1 ca. Now I want to run `composer-playground` in a docker container and I'm trying to run it with the following command:

```
docker run --network composer_default --name composer-playground -v ~/.composer:/home/composer/.composer --publish 8080:8080 --detach hyperledger/composer-playground
```

It launches the container, and I can see the `PeerAdmin` card as well as my network admin card, but when I try to connect with the network admin card, It keeps connecting with message "Please Wait: Connecting to Business Network avocado-network
using connection profile hlfv1" and after sometime, It throws `REQUEST_TIMEOUT` error.

Has anyone faced this issue, If yes, please enlighten me.

Comment: its likely its because your connection profile has 'localhost' definitions (and therefore the containers are not resolvable, when trying to contact the other docker containers from inside your 'playground' container). Suggest to see the `sed` sequence here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest (Step 9) that changes the connection.json (this assumes a 'dev' environment setup, use as appropriate for your env etc etc)

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked. And It would be great If you can post it as answer so It will help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ts likely its because your connection profile has 'localhost' definitions (and therefore the containers are not resolvable, when trying to contact the other docker containers from inside your 'playground' container). Suggest to see the sed sequence here -> hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/… (Step 9) that changes the connection.json (this assumes a 'dev' environment setup, use as appropriate for your env etc

the following 'one-liner' does the job for the localhost based Composer Dev environment setup: (in this case, my existing business network card is `admin@trade-network` and use this to

`sed -e 's/localhost:7051/peer0.org1.example.com:7051/' -e 's/localhost:7053/peer0.org1.example.com:7053/' -e 's/localhost:7054/ca.org1.example.com:7054/'  -e 's/localhost:7050/orderer.example.com:7050/'  < $HOME/.composer/cards/admin@trade-network/connection.json  > /tmp/connection.json && cp -p /tmp/connection.json $HOME/.composer/cards/admin@trade-network/`